# Multi-step and multipage Registration Form with Field_group module

Tags: users, commerce, entities

My drupal is 7 .

I use [field_group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module For grouping field and multipage registration form.

When I Add multipages to account fields only 2 groups of these fieldgroups work and other field groups show on bottom of first step.
I set field group and multipage group and multipage widget on field settings.
For content type everythings is work correctly but for user registration Form Some steps ignored.

Have anybody same problem?

Have any idea for multistep registration form with Drupal.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at these modules:

https://drupal.org/project/ctools
https://drupal.org/project/mforms

Make sure to go through their documentation for more information on how to create the multistep registration page.

You may also want to take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7-using-ctools

And you might also have a look at this module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/step

Regards,

Comment: mforms module need some codes and is very complex.STEP module needs Profile2 module and i don't like use profile2.i want create forms with fields API.unfortunately Field_group is not working for registration form correctly.thank you for your response...IS ANY Idea for use field group?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall My drupal site and use field_group module for secound time , this time everything is normal and steps are added to forms.

Thank you for responses.